# images are not displayed Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, frontend

Good day!

I have such a problem. I am writing the Next + TypeScript application. I need to make sure that as many images are displayed as in the array that I am passing through props. I decided to pass the path and just take the image already in the map. But it turns out to be an error (Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Cannot find module '../../../public/icons/zavod.svg'). the path is absolutely correct. What to do? Maybe there are other ways to display the picture?

```typescript
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from './page.module.css'
import Navbar from './ui/navbar/navbar'
import TitleBlock from './ui/titleBlock'
import Button from './ui/button/button'




const compButtonsArray = [
  { icon: '../../../public/icons/zavod.svg', label: 'Label 1', transitionDelay: '0s', countBtn: "discord-button" },
  { icon: '../../../public/icons/gazprom.svg', label: 'Label 2', transitionDelay: '0.1s', countBtn: 'twitter-button' },
  { icon: '../../../public/icons/ya.svg', label: 'Label 2', transitionDelay: '0.2s', countBtn: 'reddit-button' },
];

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <TitleBlock />
      <div className={styles.content_space}>
        <Button companyButtons={compButtonsArray}/>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

```typescript
import styles from "./button.module.css";
import clsx from 'clsx';
import Image from 'next/image';


interface ButtonProps {
    companyButtons: Array<{
      icon: string;
      label: string;
      transitionDelay: string;
      countBtn: string;
    }>;
  }

export default function Button({ companyButtons }: ButtonProps) {
    return (
        <>
            <div className={styles.btn_block}>
                <div className={styles.buttons}>
                    <button className={styles['main-button']}>
                        <Image
                            className={styles.button_logo}
                            src={require('../../../public/button_logo.svg')}
                            alt="IS_logo"
                            width={50}
                            height={50}
                            priority
                        />
                    </button>

                    {
                        companyButtons.map((button, index) => (
                                <button
                                    key={index}
                                    className={clsx(styles[`${button.countBtn}`], styles.button)}
                                    style={{ transitionDelay: `${button.transitionDelay}, ${button.transitionDelay}, ${button.transitionDelay}`, transitionProperty: 'translate, background, box-shadow' }}
                                    >
                                    <Image
                                        src={require(button.icon)} 
                                        alt={"ss"}
                                        width={30}
                                        height={30}
                                    />
                                </button>
                            )  
                        )
                    }
                </div>
                <div className={styles.text_block}>
                    <span className={styles.btn__title}>Лаборатория технологического предпринимательства</span>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/import-svgs-next-js-apps/#:%7E:text=The%20simplest%20way%20of%20using,in%20your%20application%27s%20root%20directory.), NextJS expects to load images & SVGs from the `public` folder.

> Be sure all the images you want to bundle with your application are in the public directory at build time.

You likely do not want to `require()` the images, but instead simply refer to their URLs off your deployed server.

To do so:

1. change the paths to your SVG icons to be:

```
const compButtonsArray = [
  { icon: '/icons/zavod.svg', label: 'Label 1', transitionDelay: '0s', countBtn: "discord-button" },
  { icon: '/icons/gazprom.svg', label: 'Label 2', transitionDelay: '0.1s', countBtn: 'twitter-button' },
  { icon: '/icons/ya.svg', label: 'Label 2', transitionDelay: '0.2s', countBtn: 'reddit-button' },
];
```

2. Change your `<Image>` to just be:

```
<Image
  className={styles.button_logo}
  src={'/button_logo.svg'}
  alt="IS_logo"
  width={50}
  height={50}
  priority
/>
```

Since the SVGs are deployed to your `public` folder, they are addressable from the root of your server.